# bridge edge loop for 2 closed loops of equal vertices not working

Tags: modeling

I am struggling to get a clean surface between the  2 loops (in the same plane) each of which have the same amount of vertices.
I selected

1)the inner loop via ALT LMB and then
2)the outer loop via ALT SHIFT LMB
3) edges Bridge Edge Loop

[image]

The desired result is below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi :). This is a known bug, unfortunately not of very high priority. Bugs me too :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem comes from the fact that you have inverted normals, recalculate them (select all in *Edit* mode and <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>) and the *Bridge Edge Loops* will work fine:

[image]

You can also activate the *LoopTools* addon, select the edges, right click > *LoopTools > Bridge*.

Comment: To the rescue yet again. Many thanks!